# Trying to mock a service but I get NullPointerException (JUNIT/MOCKITO)

Tags: java, junit, mockito, junit4

I'm new to Junit and Mockito unit testing. I need to unit test the method "processFiles(final File folder)"

Since I make a call to another service inside this method called myService.isFileOk(data), I think I need to mock this service to make it return true.

But as I run my test, I get a Null pointer exception.

This is a part of the code from the processFiles method:

```
  @EJB
  private transient MyService myService;

  public void processFiles(final File folder)
  {
     
      File[] fileNames = folder.listFiles();
      List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
      boolean isFirstFile = true;
      try
      {
          for (File file : fileNames)
          {
                  List<String> l = readContent(file, isFirstFile);
                  l.forEach(i -> lines.add(i));
                  isFirstFile = false;     
          }

          String[] data = lines.get(0).trim().split(";");
          if (!this.myservice.isFileOk(data))
          {
            // ...
          }
          else
          {
              // ...
          }
      }
      catch (IOException e)
      {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
```

And this is how I'm trying to test my processFile method

```
    @Mock
    public MyService myService ;

    @Rule
    public TemporaryFolder temporaryFolder = new TemporaryFolder();


    @Test
    public void testWrite2() throws IOException {

        final File tempFile1 = temporaryFolder.newFile("tempFile.txt");
        final File tempFile2 = temporaryFolder.newFile("tempFile2.txt");

        String[] data = {"a", "b" , "c" , "d"} ;
        this.myService = new MyService();


       MyService myService = Mockito.mock(MyService.class);
 
       when(myService.isFileOk(data)).thenReturn(true);


//... myclass.processFiles(file);
    }
```

Do you know how I should proceed to mock the isFileOk ? Thanks a lot in advance for your help

Comment: What is the name of the class holding the  @EJB
  private transient MyService myService;

Comment: How do you initialize the myclass instance ? My guess it is the myclass that is holding the myService

Comment: Also delete the "this.myService = new MyService();" if you are going to mock it.

Comment: Yes it is MyClass that holds the @EJB  private transient MyService myService;

Comment: And I initilize it like so :  @Mock
                                      ListFilesService listFilesService;

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to pass the mock to the class holding the instance and also use matchers:

https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.9.5/org/mockito/Matchers.html

```
when(myService.isFileOk(eq(data))).thenReturn(true);
```

You have defined also MyService two times. Once globaly and once localy inside the method. Maybe you shouyld consider deleting one of the two.

You can use reflection to set the
`private transient MyService myService;`  in `MyClass`

```
Field myServiceField = myclass.getClass().getDeclaredField("myService");
myServiceField.setAccessible(true);
f1.set(myClass, mock);
```

And then invoke:

```
myclass.processFiles(file);
```

Now your mock should be initialized.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is that you are trying to mock the @EJB, which will be injected by your container service in actual runtime.

However, in your test, you are not using a container service, so the service doesn't get injected and remains null in your instance of your class.

In essence, you are looking for the EJB equivalent of Spring's "@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)" annotation, which performs injection on your test case executions.

As far as I know, EJB doesn't have this, but I haven't used it in a while so I could be wrong.  If it indeed doesn't have it, the next thing you can do is to use reflection to force it in.